# TFS API: Retrieving the list of teams for a team project

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm using the below nugget packages in order to integrate some of the TFS functionality:

> Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
>   Blockquote
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client
>   Blockquote
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client
>   Blockquote
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient

and I have difficulties finding the right method to retrieve the teams for a specific team project.

Based on the TFS REST API reference I should find the GetTeams method in the ProjectHttpClient class but it's missing.

[image]

Do you have any idea where I could find this method? Or how can I get the list of teams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the TeamHttpClient:

```
var client = new TeamHttpClient();
client.GetTeamsAsync("projectId");
```